# How can I ensure that a line of code is executed only once using React hooks in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I want a line of code in a react component to be executed only when the component is mounted, and not when it re-renders. In a stateful component, I would do this in `componentDidMount`/`componentWillMount` method.

How can I do this using hooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for reacts `useEffect` hook. It is the hook replacement for componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount. You can use it like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("only executed once")
}, [])
```

Note the empty array as second argument, which defines the dependencies for this effect. In this case you want to have no dependency, so that the effect wont be executed again.

There is a good article on how to replace the previous lifecycle functions with hooks available [here](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/).

Answer (score 1):

// Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
useEffect(() => {}, [])

React Docs. Hooks-Using the Effect Hook. - > https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html